# Subfigures not centered with captions

Tags: graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment, thesis

Like my title says. I have created two subfigures but they are not centered to the subcaptions. Need some help fixing this. Also not sure if this is the most efficient way to make subfigures in latex I just kinda forced it to work. I was having trouble with the spacing between the 2 figures.

```
\begin{figure}
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{pics/Soil concentrtion A&B.jpg}
     \caption{A \& B sites}
     \label{fig:y equals x}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hspace{1in}
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{pics/Soil concentration C&D.jpg}
     \caption{C \& D sites}
     \label{fig:three sin x}
 \end{subfigure}
   \caption{Uranium Concentrations at soil locations}
 \end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Somewhere in your code there is something like `\captionsetup[subfigure]{singlelinecheck=false}`.

Answer (score 1):

- As @JohnKormylo say in his comment, cause of your problem is not in code fragment but somewhere else, preassembly in document preamble, where is set  `singlelinecheck=false`.
- Lesson: always prepare a complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem.
- An example of the MWE, which produce desired result, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
     \includegraphics{example-image-a}
     \caption{A \& B sites}
     \label{fig:y equals x}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
     \includegraphics{example-image-b}
     \caption{C \& D sites}
     \label{fig:three sin x}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Uranium Concentrations at soil locations}
    \label{fig:uranium}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

in which is used default settings for captions and subcaptions. They do not contain mentioned instruction `singlelinecheck=false`. Result of compilation is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you have more than your question):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{72pt}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[x=72pt]
                \draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1); 
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \subcaption{One}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{72pt}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[x=72pt]
                \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,1); 
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \subcaption{Two}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{All for one and one for all}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.40]{example-image}
            \caption{A \& B sites}
            \label{fig:y equals x}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hspace{1in}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.40]{example-image}
            \caption{C \& D sites}
            \label{fig:three sin x}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Uranium Concentrations at soil locations}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**: With few adds and changes in the code you can also have this:

[image]